# How can we convert a datetime into a string representing a Unix timestamp in nanoseconds using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to use Matlab to generate a string which contains a Unix timestamp in nanoseconds (i.e nanoseconds since 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00, the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) from an input date string.

For example, if my input is only 1 ns after the start of the epoch, then the following code works:

```
t0 = datetime('01-Jan-1970 00:00:00.000000000','Format','dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS');
t1 = datetime('01-Jan-1970 00:00:00.000000001','Format','dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS');

dt_ns = seconds(t1 - t0)*1e9
dt_ns_string = sprintf('%.0f',dt_ns)

dt_ns_string =

    '1'
```

and I have the nanosecond precision that I need.

However, if I instead for `t1` use a date around today:

```
t1 = datetime('16-Jun-2020 00:00:00.000000001','Format','dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS');
```

then the output is the following:

```
dt_ns_string =

    '1592265600000000000'
```

and I have lost the final nanosecond precision on the end of the string (final character should be a "1").

How can I solve this?

---

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments there is also the Matlab function `posixtime()` which eliminates the need to manually subtract the datetime corresponding to 01-Jan-1970. However, this results in the same problem:

```
dt_ns_posix = posixtime(t1)*1e9
sprintf('%.0f',dt_ns_posix)

    '1592265600000000000'
```

Comment: are you looking for [posixtime](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.posixtime.html)?

Comment: Even with posxtime I could not manage to give the final nanosecond characters on the end. Although if you can provide a basic example using posxtime I'd love to see it!

Comment: Edited the question to show that it gives the same result.

Comment: I'd like to check that for myself but the machine I run MATLAB on is currently under repairs (lame excuse, I know)... the documentation does not say much about precision, maybe it's just microseconds? Or is it only a matter of display?

Comment: I think it is something related to the fact posixtime() might give back a double, but since I need 19 characters to represent my string I think double is insufficient. I am looking at uint64 datatype in Matlab, but cannot solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that sideteps the loss of precision inherent to `double`:

1. Use [`between`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.between.html) with the optional third input to get the time difference as a `calendarDuration` scalar indicating days, hours, minutes and seconds.
2. Convert to `char` and extract the individual numbers of days, hours, minutes and seconds.
3. Multiply each value by `1e9` and convert to `uint64`. Note that each individual value multiplied by `1e9` gives an integer that is well within the limits of floating-point precision (i.e. is not larger than `2^53`).
4. Use multiplication and [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) with the `'native'` option to obtain the total number of nanoseconds as a `uint64` value.

```
t0 = datetime('01-Jan-1970 00:00:00.000000000','Format','dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS');
t1 = datetime('16-Jun-2020 00:00:00.000000001','Format','dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS');
b = between(t0, t1, {'Days', 'Time'});
t = str2double(regexp(char(b), '(?<=(^| )).+?(?=[dhms$])', 'match')); % split d, h, m, s
if numel(t)==3 % if the number of days is 0 it will not be present
  t = [0 t];
end
result = sum(uint64(t*1e9).*uint64([86400 3600 60 1]), 'native'); % sum as uint64
```

This gives

```
result =
  uint64
   1592265600000000001
```